# ¿estara bien mi codigo?

Tags: python, funciones

necesito crear un programa en Python lea números ingresados y luego devuelva el total
se debe desarrollar utilizando recursión. no se puede utilizar ciclos, se ingresan números hasta que el usuario ingrese espacio si el primer input es un espacio debe imprimir 0

hasta el momento he podido crear lo siguiente:

```
def sumar(lista):
if len(lista) == 1:
    print(lista[0])
    return lista[0]
else:
    print(lista[0])
    return lista[0] + sumar(lista[1:])
 ` listaNumeros = []
 valor=int(input("ingresa un valor:"))
 if valor != 1:
       listaNumeros.append(valor)
 elif valor == " ":
      print("0")

 print("Total Sumado: ", sumar(listaNumeros)) `
```

en general funciona pero no se como hacer pra que me vuelva a pedir el valor sin usar un ciclo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cual es el problema??? lo probaste???

Comment: OK.. tu input debe estar dentro de la recursion.. y asi como esta, ese codigo no funciona.. en python la identacion es todo.. por favor, identa el codigo como corresponde...

Comment: como dentro de la recursion, cuando retorno la lista[0]+ sumar... despues de esa linea de codigo, y como mal identada si a mi me funciona solo que no me vuelve a pedir el valor¿?

Comment: Hay 1.001 problemas donde la recursión es la respuesta precisa. Tu profesor no conoce ningun de ellos.

Comment: El código en la pregunta está mal indentado. La recursion no se ve claramente en tu código. ¿Cuál es el caso base? Por lo que puedo entender del problema planteado, el caso base depende de la entrada del usuario y no de los elementos de la lista.